# How to have timing and retry policy when Apollo gateway is failing?

Tags: microservices, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

The Apollo Gateway module requires a list of `GraphQL` servers to connect to. If any of these services miss responding with a success code to the Apollo Gateway, the whole Gateway will exit with a failed status.

There should be a retry policy for when the gateway is failing. Apollo Gateway initialization so that it is managed by a retry function in case of failure.

How can I do that?

Comment: did you check this https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/retry/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find the solution:

With `gateway.load()` we could catch the errors and do whatever we want.